# How can I upload large files by chunk, pieces?

Tags: file-upload, upload, chunking

I have got a little file sharing webpage. It's free to use it. I would like to upload files between 0mb and 1GB. I'm searching in Google since two days, but I can't find anything what I needed...

My webpage: http://boxy.tigyisolutions.hu However I can upload only 20-30mb now. I would like **upload only 1 file at once.** But it may be bigger than 500-600mb ... Can anyone help me?

I tried jquery fileupload, but it's uploading nothing for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Blob.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Blob) method will allow you to split up a file client-side into chunks.  You must then send each chunk individually.  This will only work on browsers that support the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File).

If you don't want to write this code yourself, [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com) is a javascript uploader library that has the ability to chunk files for you and send them to your server.

Comment: Hi there,
fine uploader didn't work for me, but I found this one: http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/
This is great and working for me, there is only one problem yet. I would like use the form demo from demos, but I would like remove the form elements.. but if I remove name, or the other I cant send the form...

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't work for me"?  What specific problem did you have? I can assure you, the file chunking feature works just fine.

Comment: error #2038 with this, and I tried swfupload.. same error.. :-(

Comment: I'm finding it hard to believe that you had this error with Fine Uploader, since I believe this is a Flash-specific error code, and Fine Uploader does not use Flash.

Comment: Ok... You are right.. That's name was similar to fineuploader... But now I tried it, but I don't know how to upload file with that.. It doesnt upload anything for me... However swfupload works now. That's very easy to use... The problem is only: i get 2038 error with that if i try upload 600+MB... I can upload 100-300MB with no problem... :-) I have edited php.ini for max upload size 2500MB, and timeout for 9999.. and FcgidMaxRequestLen to 2147483648 bytes ... but with large files 2038 error...

Comment: @RayNicholus why should the large files be divided to chunks for uploading them ?

Comment: so does this mean we have to make multiple http request to the backend server for each chunk?