# php - Split large files to smaller chunks for uploading

Tags: php, file-upload

I am making a website for uploading large video files using PHP. But the problem is that i get (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET) error while uploading large files which take more time to upload. It works fine for small files (less than 80-90mb) which take less time to upload. I have added these lines to my user.ini file but still nothing.

```
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600
memory_limit = 1024M
post_max_size = 1024M
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
```

Is there a way to break large files into smaller pieces which can be uploaded without this timeout error or is there any other better way for uploading large files.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646355/how-can-i-upload-large-files-by-chunk-pieces

Comment: [set_time_limit(0)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Answer (score 1):

you can use split command in Linux

https://linux.die.net/man/1/split

Comment: Looking in your question past the question line .. you're actually receiving this files on the sever via php. I'm not aware of truly "portable" frontend way of splitting files to smaller chunks for upload. I can imagine upload files over websocket but this requires that javascript being able to "read" file from the client machine  something that is not generally allowed.

Comment: OK! here is something to start reading if you're going "client way" https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI

Other solution: run SFTP server over which the upload happens. Offer PHP file selection interface from the  SFTP uploaded files