# Unable to upload large files on shared hosting?

Tags: php, laravel, server, upload, shared-hosting

I have shared hosting on godaddy. I am uploading a large video files upto 150 MB on server. It starts upload & upload some part of video upto 15% but after that connection is broken. I get below error

```
503 - SERVICE UNAVAILABLE
```

I have also manually configured the php.ini file below like

```
post_max_size = 512M
max_execution_time = 800
```

I am not sure if it is the programatically issue because i am able to upload small video on good connection. But as video size is large then i face the issue.

Kindly let me know what is the issue ?

Comment: A note with Godaddy: depending on your hosting plan, you may not be able to set your PHP upload to 512M. https://ca.godaddy.com/help/php-upload-limits-on-shared-hosting-1475

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646355/how-can-i-upload-large-files-by-chunk-pieces) and [this](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads)

Answer (score 3):

Change your upload_max_filesize to the same amount as well

```
upload_max_filesize = 512M
post_max_size = 512M
```

You may need to increase your memory as well

```
memory_limit = 32M
```

Dont forget to restart your server after updating the `php.ini` file

Comment: This does not work for me. if file is uploaded within 6 minutes then its success otherwise i get 503 error

Comment: The browser or the server? Try setting the `set_time_limit(0)` Contact godaddy you might not have a plan with the server resources to upload a very large file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an FTP connection for file upload , there is an option in the Filezilla to increase the wait time . Hope this works for you .